# What's the best way to find a relationship between two tables in an edmx model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been handed a project with a pretty complex database schema.  There's no database diagram in SQL, but there is one in the edmx model file.  I'm trying to find the relationship between two entities.  When I write a lambda expression in the controller, I can say

`<entity>.Where(x => x.ChildTable.FieldA == 'Test'),`

but, I don't have any way to know what the relationship is between X and ChildTable.  When I open the edmx file, I can see the tables and I can see all the lines that represent the relationships, but because there are so many, it's really difficult to find a specific relationship between 2 specific tables.  Is there a utility in VS that will allow me to do that easily?

Comment: You can open the Class specifc for the entity that you want to know the relation and check out this properties.

Comment: I don't see a relationship specified in the class file.  Also, what if there are 3 physical tables included in a 2-entity relationship (as is the case here)?
So, ParentTable.ChildTable is the relationship in the model, but in the actual database it's like, "ParentTable.XRefTable.ChildTable."

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is, I have a Lambda expression I want to convert to a SQL query to get the same results in Query Analyzer.

Comment: You can always log the SQL and examine it (context.Database.Log = Console.Write; ). The EF produced can be verbose, but you should be able to decipher the joins. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I mean, not Query Analyzer... SSMS.  Damn Stack Exchange and its stupid rules.

Comment: Steve Greene... how do you do that?

Comment: You can create sub diagrams in the edmx.